# Use Intl inside a Flutter Component Library

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization, intl

I use intl in a Flutter project but I wanted to extract some components into an external library and use it as a dependency to my main project.

It works but one of the component use intl to define a text. Inside the main project this is not a problem as intl is configured correctly however inside the library I do not know how to use intl.

I defined the variable correctly but I am getting this error
`The getter 'my_key' was called on null.`

The error occurs because I did not set up `localizationsDelegates` as I do not have `MaterialApp` inside the component library.

Is it possible to use intl in this context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/localizely/flutter-intl-intellij/issues/22#issuecomment-616816826)

You need to give another name into

```
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
  class_name: WhateverYouWant
```

And declare it into `localizationsDelegates` in your main project